# how to search a keyword in all nodes and all properties of umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

hello i have created indexing in umbraco to search any keyword in umbraco for which i had made a user control and cretead a search criteria and filter but it is displaying list of that nodes which contain alias name bodyText but i want list of all nodes which doesnt have alias name bodytext because it is not possible to give all the property alias name bodytext so what should i do to search all nodes and all properties in umbraco

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SearchTerm = Request.QueryString["s"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm)) return;

        var criteria = ExamineManager.Instance
                .SearchProviderCollection["DemoSearcher"]
                .CreateSearchCriteria(UmbracoExamine.IndexTypes.Content);

        var filter = criteria
        .GroupedOr(new string[] { "nodeName", "bodyText" }, SearchTerm)
        .Compile();



       SearchResults = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["DemoSearcher"].Search(filter);

        SearchResultListing.DataSource = SearchResults;
        SearchResultListing.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to search through every type of field, because searching integer fields or guids or even the json or xml of a multi-node picker won't necessarily get what you expect.

You can enumerate the properties of each node and then if the property is of a type (like a textbox) that you want to search you can use the following as a basis for searching textboxes that aren't necessarily called bodyText:

```
foreach(node in nodes)
{

  var props = node.PropertiesAsList;

  foreach (var prop in props)  
  {
    if (@prop.Value.GetType() == " ... type you want to search ... ")
    {
      var fieldValue = node.getProperty(@prop.Alias).Value;
      ... search fieldvalue ...
    }
  }
}
```